# How to solve error "FAILURE:Build failed with an exception" in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, exception, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.0-6040484 available for offline mode.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 267ms
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings/build, execution, Deployment/ gradle/ and uncheck offline work and run build again

Answer (score 0):

If all the think is best but not work you add this line

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.sendpulse.sendpulse"

```
minSdkVersion 15

targetSdkVersion 21

multiDexEnabled true //Add me//
```

}